# How to compare two characters in Java in if conditon?

Tags: java

How can I compare two characters in Java?

```
while(s1.hasNext()) {
    if(a[j].equals('x')
        x++;
    if(a[j].equals('y')
        y++;
}
```

I have repeated the loop using for loop for n times and a[j] is an array. I am getting the error at if condition inside the while loop. Could anyone please explain me about the error?

Comment: Bracket not closed properly if(a[j].equals('x'))

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: char cannot be dereferenced..at the if condition line

Answer (score 0):

you can also compare characters using `==` as following:

```
while(s1.hasNext())
{
    if(a[j] == 'x')
    x++;
    if(a[j]=='y')
    y++;
}
```

here array `a` should be a character array.

If `a` is a string than you have to use `s.charAt(int index)` to get desired character, as following:

```
while(s1.hasNext())
{
    if(a.charAt(j) == 'x')
    x++;
    if(a.charAt(j) == 'y')
    y++;
}
```

Comment: a is not a string it is an character array.. and also i have written what you said but getting the same errors at the if condition only..

Comment: what is error??@Ch_03

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
if(a.charAt(j) == 'x')
symbol: method charAt(int)
location: variable a of type char[]

Comment: I said if `a` is string than use `a.charAt()`. If it is an array than use my 1st snippet. @Ch_03

Comment: the first snippet i had tried already but if has not been worked..because there are no compilation errors but i haven't got the output..

Comment: post your whole code@Ch_03

Comment: @Ch_03 if your array of character type then u have use like the first snippet